# googlecontacts api duplicate when insert batch contacts

Tags: php, google-contacts-api, google-client

I insert with php apiclient batch and duplicate the entries in google contacts

I use:

```
  $contactXML =
"<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
      xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'
      xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
      xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>
  <entry>
    <batch:id>create</batch:id>
    <batch:operation type='insert'/>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2008#contact'/>
    <gd:name>
      <gd:fullName>Elizabeth Bennet</gd:fullName>
      <gd:givenName>Elizabeth</gd:givenName>
      <gd:familyName>Bennet</gd:familyName>
    </gd:name>
    <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home' address='liz@gmail.com' primary='true'/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <batch:id>create2</batch:id>
    <batch:operation type='insert'/>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2008#contact'/>
    <gd:name>
      <gd:fullName>maria pomez</gd:fullName>
      <gd:givenName>maria</gd:givenName>
      <gd:familyName>pomez</gd:familyName>
    </gd:name>
    <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home' address='mariasarmiento@gmail.com' primary='true'/>
  </entry>

</feed>
";

$headers = array(
  'Host' => 'www.google.com',
  'Gdata-version' => '3.0',
  'Content-length' => strlen($contactXML),
  'Content-type' => 'application/atom+xml',
  'alt' => 'json',
  'CURLOPT_SSLVERSION' => '3'
);

$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch';

$resultado = $httpClient->post($url, ['headers' => $headers, 'body' => $contactXML]);
```

But the contacts was duplicated.

Is so strange, when use xdebug for debug the code not duplicate contacts.

I saw the network petitions of developers tools of navigator and only make one petition for page.

Can anyone help me?

Thx

Sorry for my english

Comment: Since this is PHP, is it possible the browser sent two requests? The Contacts API has no way of distinguishing repeated requests as the same duplicated request and so would create the same contacts over and over again if the same request is replayed.

Comment: I make only one request

Comment: How can i check if make two request?

Comment: Has been fixed by updating googleclient php to 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Has been fixed by updating googleclient php to 2.1.1